# assign bash variable using a ternary like syntax

Tags: bash

I have the following bash code:

```
if [ $NOD_ENV = "production" ]; then IS_PRODUCTION=1; else IS_PRODUCTION=0; fi
if [ $IS_PRODUCTION ]; then VALUE="$VALUE_PRODUCTION"; else CDN_HEADER_VALUE="$PRODUCTION"; fi
# etc
fi
```

I am getting some unexpected output assigning variables this way.  How could I do this better?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly test the value of `$IS_PRODUCTION`:

```
if [ $IS_PRODUCTION = 0 ]; then  ...
```

`if [ $IS_PRODUCTION ]` only tests whether the length of `$IS_PRODUCTION` is non-zero.

As a side note, [ is actually a program, and you can see the options for it by running `/usr/bin/[ --help` (the /usr/bin seems important on my system for some reason ...)

Answer (score 1):

It's a cool trick to set boolean variable in bash to the string "true" or "false":

```
if [ $NOD_ENV = "production" ]; then IS_PRODUCTION=true; else IS_PRODUCTION=false; fi
if "$IS_PRODUCTION"; then VALUE="$VALUE_PRODUCTION"; else CDN_HEADER_VALUE="$PRODUCTION"; fi;
```

What happens here, is that IS_PRODUCTION has the **string** "true" or "false". Once you run `if "$IS_PRODUCTION"` the variable is expanded which results in `if true` or `if false`. `true` and `false` are builtin commands, which get run, and return - zero status for `true` and non-zero status for `false`.